# Analytic continuation of partitions generating function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

Let $p_k(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ with exactly $k$ parts. It is known that 
$$ f_k(x)=\sum_n p_k(n)x^n=x^k\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{1-x^i}.$$

My question is: is there a known analytic continuation of the function $f_k(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product formula is an analytic continuation of $f_k$. Note that in the product formula, $f_k$ is a finite product of meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$, so it is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ (and therefore analytic on every point that is not a pole). However, it’s important to note that the full partitions generating function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p(x)x^n=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^n}$$ does *not* have an analytic continuation because it has a singularity at every root of unity, which are dense in the unit circle. Thus, it is lacunary.

Comment: Is there an integral representation of $f_k(x)$? I want to compute its Fourier transform...